# WCF routing how to add Backuplist Programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-routing

I'm using WCF routing service and I'm trying to Implement failover, I need to add filter table backuplist programmatically, this is a sample  configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
          <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="*" name="ServiceOperation1" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/Service2" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="*" name="ServiceOperation2" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/Service3" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="*" name="ServiceOperation3" />
          </client>
          <routing>
            <filters>
              <filter name="MatchAllFilter" filterType="MatchAll" />
            </filters>
            <filterTables>
              <filterTable name="RoutingTable">
                <add filterName="MatchAllFilter" endpointName="ServiceOperation1" backupList="BackUps" />
              </filterTable>
            </filterTables>
            <backupLists>
              <backupList name="BackUps">
                <add endpointName="ServiceOperation2"/>
                <add endpointName="ServiceOperation3" />
              </backupList>
            </backupLists>
          </routing>
          <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="">
                <routing filterTableName="RoutingTable" />
              </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
          </behaviors>
            <services>
                <service name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
                  <endpoint address="binary" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                           contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" name="VirtualEndpoint" />
                    <host>
                        <baseAddresses>
                            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/RoutingService/Router" />
                        </baseAddresses>
                    </host>
                </service>
            </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I was able to add FilterTable which I found example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118201/wcf-routing-how-to-correctly-add-filter-table-programmatically)

here is my code snippet:

```
var routingHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RoutingService));
var routingEp = routingHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter), mybinding, url);      
var filterTable = new MessageFilterTable<IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();   
filterTable.Add(new MatchAllMessageFilter(), new List<ServiceEndpoint>()
                        {
                            serviceoperation1Endpoint
                        });


 routingHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(
                              new RoutingBehavior(new RoutingConfiguration(filterTable, false)));

routingHost.open();
```

so in my scenario `ServiceOperation2` and `ServiceOperation3` are the backup endpoints, I made lots of research I coudn't find a way to add backuplist Programmatically

any Idea how can I add backuplist to filterTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this solution to dynamically generate config file

In my scenario, I load my endpoints from database and generated routing service configuration out of it,

```
public class MyServiceEndPoint 
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//// generates routing service configuration section, including client enoints/filterTable/backups and routing service behavior
private void CreateRoutingConfiguration(List<MyServiceEndPoint> serviceEndpoints)
{
     ///// group endopints by Name, each service could have multiple endpoints ( 1 main and n backup endpoints)
    var groupedEndpoitns = (from endp in serviceEndpoints
                                    group endp by endp.Name into endpGroup
                                    select new { ServiceName = endpGroup.Key, EndPoint = endpGroup }).ToList();



    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var serviceModelSectionGroup = System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

    var routingSection = (RoutingSection)serviceModelSectionGroup.Sections["routing"];
    var clientsection = (ClientSection)serviceModelSectionGroup.Sections["client"];
    var bindingSection = (BindingsSection)serviceModelSectionGroup.Sections["bindings"];
    var behaviorSection = (BehaviorsSection)serviceModelSectionGroup.Sections["behaviors"];

    bindingSection.NetTcpBinding.Bindings.Clear();
    clientsection.Endpoints.Clear();
    var filterTable = new FilterTableEntryCollection() { Name = "RoutingTable" };
    routingSection.Filters.Clear();
    routingSection.FilterTables.Clear();
    routingSection.BackupLists.Clear();

    var nettcpBinding = new NetTcpBindingElement()
    {
        Name = "myTcpBinding",
        TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,        
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),

    };

    nettcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    bindingSection.NetTcpBinding.Bindings.Add(nettcpBinding);


    foreach (var endpointGroup in groupedEndpoitns)
    {
        var backupListItem = new BackupEndpointCollection();
        backupListItem.Name = endpointGroup.ServiceName + "Backup";

        var filter = new FilterElement();
        filter.Name = endpointGroup.ServiceName + "Filter";
        filter.FilterType = FilterType.Custom;
        filter.CustomType = "MyServiceContractMessageFilterType,asemblyName";
        filter.FilterData = endpointGroup.EndPoint.FirstOrDefault().ClientTypeName;
        routingSection.Filters.Add(filter);

        int endpointCount = 0;
        List<ChannelEndpointElement> channelEndpoints = new List<ChannelEndpointElement>();
        foreach (var endpoint in endpointGroup.EndPoint)
        {
            endpointCount++;
            var channelEndpoint = new ChannelEndpointElement();
            channelEndpoint.Address = new Uri(endpoint.Url);
            channelEndpoint.Binding = "netTcpBinding";
            channelEndpoint.BindingConfiguration = "myTcpBinding";
            channelEndpoint.Contract = "*";
            channelEndpoint.Name = $"{endpoint.Name}EndPoint{endpointCount}";
            clientsection.Endpoints.Add(channelEndpoint);
            channelEndpoints.Add(channelEndpoint);

        }

        var firstChannelEndpoint = channelEndpoints.FirstOrDefault(); /// this endpoint will be selected as main endpoint
        var filterTableItem = new FilterTableEntryElement();
        filterTableItem.FilterName = filter.Name;
        filterTableItem.EndpointName = firstChannelEndpoint.Name;
        filterTableItem.BackupList = backupListItem.Name;
        filterTable.Add(filterTableItem);    

        foreach (var backupEndpoints in channelEndpoints)
        {
            backupListItem.Add(new BackupEndpointElement() { EndpointName = backupEndpoints.Name });
            routingSection.BackupLists.Add(backupListItem);
        }
    }

    routingSection.FilterTables.Add(filterTable);    
    behaviorSection.ServiceBehaviors.Clear();
    var behavior = new ServiceBehaviorElement();
    behavior.Add(new RoutingExtensionElement() { FilterTableName = filterTable.Name });
    behaviorSection.ServiceBehaviors.Add(behavior);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, false);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel/routing");
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel/client");        
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel/behaviors");
}
```

so first I generated configuration file 
and than create an intance of routing service like:

```
CreateRoutingConfiguration(serviceEndpoints);
routingHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RoutingService));
routingHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter), mybinding, $"net.tcp://localhost:6000/Router");
routingHost.Open();
```

hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but a quick look through the documentation on MSDN for [Message Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-filters#filter-tables) shows that alternative backup endpoints are configured via the [FilterTableElementEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-filters#filter-tables) class (BackupList property).

> A filter table is a named collection of FilterTableEntryElement
>   objects that define the association between a filter, a primary
>   destination endpoint, and a ***list of alternative backup endpoints***. The
>   filter table entries also allow you to specify an optional priority
>   for each filter condition.

Check for Filter Table and BackupList on Google, and you'll come across examples of usage of this. [This example](https://github.com/Duikmeester/WF_WCF_Samples/blob/master/WCF/Basic/RoutingServices/ErrorHandling%20and%20Bridging/CS/RoutingService/routing.cs) looks particularly promising with plenty of comments describing the steps.

Comment: thanks for your help but I already looked at those documentations but `FilterTableElementEntry` can't be changed at runtime or as far as I know, I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323696(v=vs.100).aspx) but apparently we can only apply changes of `serviceElement` sections at runtime

Comment: It seems to me that it is possible. The example I posted in my last sentence there, shows how the BackupList is constructed and then used to construct the RoutingConfiguration and ServiceHost. That actually looks like a nice little self contained example. Why not try to use that as a base to see if you can configure your service as you have shown it in your question.

Comment: if I add backup endpoints in filter table( as the example you provided and also my code like `filterTable.Add(new MatchAllMessageFilter(), new List<ServiceEndpoint>()
                        {
                            serviceoperation1Endpoint, serviceoperation2Endpoint, serviceoperation3Endpoint
                        });`  it throws `Multiple filters matched` exception

Comment: apparently it matches all endpints, it should be `1 main endpoint` and `2 backup endpoints` , the same like configuration, or I'm missing something...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you are setting up your service with regards to your [Addresses, Bindings and Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/endpoints-addresses-bindings-and-contracts). Your code snippet doesn't provide enough information to show what is being done with regards to that. You can look at the [`Filters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.multiplefiltermatchesexception.filters(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get an idea of the filters that caused the exception to be thrown though.